# Fetching data instantly using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, mysqli

I want to create a form in where  the user have to select a section from a list then another list shows the options correspending to this section.
I'm null in jquery / js , here is my code that i want to edit:

```
<select name="section"   class="span8" required>
        <option selected disabled>Section</option>

        <?php 


        $sq=mysqli_query($connection->con,"select * from sections");
        while($sf=mysqli_fetch_array($sq))
        {
        echo "<option value='".$sf['section_name']."'>".$sf['section_name']."</option>";
        }

        ?>

        </select>
        <select name="matiere"   class="span8" required>
        <option selected disabled>Matière</option>
        <option value="option1">option1</option>
        <option value="option2">option2</option>
        </select>
```

Comment: Well, go with the code and tell us the error that you got.

Comment: No error with this code , what i need in here is a jquery code to instantly change the second list.

Comment: Hire a developer, I'm available to do that for you

Comment: the Internet has far too much information in regards to tutorials. Voting to close as too broad

Comment: @Michelem anch'io ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Your right you need **jQuery** for it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("select[name='section']").on("change",function(){
      value_select = $(this).val();
      // perform a ajax operation 
          $.ajax({
            url: 'path/to/thefile.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                   select_value : value_select,
                   more_value : more_value
                   
                 },
            success: function (data) {
                // response you get from your server side code 
               // supposing your response will have 
                // all options in form of string 
               $("select[name='matiere']").html(data);
            }
        });
    }); 

 });
```

the code might not be easy at once
here have a reference

> http://api.jquery.com/
>
> http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: thanks , but i don't get it , if you're free , can you get in teamviewer for 5 minutes ?

Comment: i dont have teamviewer and i am at office. but you can read about it. its not that tough.. and let me know if i can help you with comments.. verify my answer if it was helpful. so it may be helpful to others

Comment: you will be needing ajax and jquery a lot.. better start studding now

Comment: you think so and i know that for sure... happy to help

Answer (score 0):

### Instead of feeding the answer to you with spoon, I shall tell you the steps to achieve

As you need to achieve your goal in your option select

**Step 1 :**

**Detect your input**

Your case : Something in your option select

```
$('select').on('change', function (e) {
});
```

**Step 2 :**

**Fire the Action**

In your case you shall call something to that you wanted to do. To do some action without refreshing the page you shall use ajax-jquery call

Inside your option select change function

```
$.ajax({
   url: "yoururl",
    type: "POST",
    data: yourdata,
    async: false,
    success: function (msg) 
    {
     console.log('youroutput');
    },
});
```

**Step 3 :**

**Do your output**

```
$("#youroutputdiv").html(data);
```

You shall do the output in the success event where i do console to see the output.

Comment: Thanks i'll read a bit about jquery and ajax and then i'll get it simply.